# Limitations of Query Activity in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, journeybuilder

how to check and match data in column1 inside table 1 with column2 inside table 2 and get the updated values in side table 3

table 1

```
ID name: status : age

1  john   F       28
2  peter  G       20
3  Roger  K       67
```

Table 2:

```
ID name: status : age

1  john   Y       28
2  peter  J       20
3  Roger  K       67
4  trump  U       120
5  Donald F       450
```

Table 3 should contain the updated values

```
1  john   Y       28
2  peter  J       20
3  Roger  K       67
```

I need to get the updated status of IDs present in table 1 in table 3 how can I do that.

Note: I am using exacttarget SQL activity and update and many more functionalities does not work so I need some work around> I have tried this but this does not work.

```
UPDATE
    1C-C1-MatchStatus_72hoursSubscribers
SET
    1C-C1-MatchStatus_72hoursSubscribers.current_status = B.current_status
FROM
   1C-C1-MatchStatus_72hoursSubscribers A
INNER JOIN
    a_query B
ON 
   A.current_status = B.current_status
```

Goal is to use this third DE in decision split which will segregate subscribers based on their current status. when they were injected it was different and after three days it might be possible that status is changed now.

Answer (score 1):

This query will output values from Table 2 where ID's exist in both (A & B), however the "status" is different between the tables:

```
SELECT
A.Id
,B.name
,B.status
,B.age
FROM [Table 1] as A
INNER JOIN [Table 2] as B ON A.Id = B.Id
WHERE A.status != B.status
```

Assumptions:

- ID is the **Primary Key** on both tables
- Only ID's that appear in **both** Tables are to be considered
- You want the "**new**" values from Table 2, not the "old" values in Table 1

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure **Update** or **Set** are supported in Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

Your join is also not going to create on view where the status has not changed. You will have to join them on a column whose values will stay the same.

Here is how I would do it:

```
SELECT
A.Id
,A.name
,B.status
A.age

FROM [Table 1] A

JOIN [Table 2] B ON 

A.name = B.name
```

Comment: Thanks @Data_Kid I already did that. lets see if it gives proper results. and one thing I didn't get was what exactly you mean when you say "Your join is also not going to create on view where the status has not changed"

Comment: @pragyanshukukreti since you are looking to create a table that captures a change in status, joining them on the status column will only return values where the status has NOT changed.

Comment: @pragyanshukukreti did it work?